# Rate-limit the email alerts sent by aws lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have used lambda function(python) to receive cloudwatch logs and send alerts(emails) to recipients using SNS service. But, the recipients are getting too many emails within say, a minute. Is there a way to rate-limit the alerts to like, 1 alert per min as long as the alert is the same message?

Comment: Possible? Yes. But (to me) this sounds like logic you need to build yourself rather than some built-in functionality for that.

Comment: Any ideas on that. I'm new to AWS and Python. Wondering if I can add some logic to python.

Comment: At a very high level: if you want to send alerts immediately but only if the same message hasn't been sent in the last 60 seconds, then you need to store the messages and a timestamp somewhere that lambda can read and so determine whether to send an alert for that message. I'd suggest a map of message -> timestamp. Look up the message value; if not found or now - timestamp > 1m, send notification and insert or update map with new timestamp; else it was sent recently so ignore.

Comment: I had a system once that would check a system every _x_ minutes and send a message if it was down. However, this meant that a prolonged outage would cause messages to be sent every 5 minutes. I then changed it to only send when the status _changed_ (eg "Up now" or "Down now"), but that caused problems when there was short system instability. I then resolved it by going into 'yellow alert' when a problem was detected the first time, and then going into 'red alert' when the problem continued. I then configured it to only send a message upon entry to 'red alert' and when it went back to 'green'.